# Computation in a Permutation Group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $\sigma , \tau \in S_3$ and $x \in X$. I need to show that for $\sigma=(1 \ 2) $ and $\tau=(2 \ 3)$, and $x = (1,2,3)$ that $(\sigma \circ \tau) \circ x \neq \sigma \circ (\tau \circ x)$. I understand how to do $(\sigma \circ \tau)$ but I don't understand how to compute the next step, or $(\tau \circ x)$.

Comment: Please clarify the notations

Comment: Just edited the problem!

Comment: Can you explain in the post how to do $\sigma\tau$? I don't see how you can know how to compute that but not $\tau x$.

Comment: What is $x\in X$? Is it a function?

Comment: What result did you get for $\sigma\circ\tau$?

Answer (score 1):

It's  false as permutation composition is associative